# Loading Movies from Disk in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 5 and C# and I would like to load a movie from anywhere on disk at run-time rather than from the Resources folder.

This is possible to do with regular image textures using the .LoadImage (bytes) method in Texture2D type for example, but there does not appear to be an equivalent for MovieTexture.

The code shows how to do it from the resources folder, but how could i modify it to load from disk?

Thanks

```
public void loadVideo (GameObject container, string video)
{
    // Load MovieTexture from Resources Folder
    MovieTexture mat = (MovieTexture)Resources.Load(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(video), typeof(MovieTexture));

    MeshRenderer ren = container.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    ren.material.mainTexture = mat;    
    mat.Play();      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Use the WWW class to to this.

```
IEnumerator loadAndPlay(){
WWW diskMovieDir = new WWW("file:///C:/yourvideoDir/video.mp4");

//Wait for file finish loading
while(!diskMovieDir.isDone){
yield return null;
}

//Save the loaded movie from WWW to movetexture
MovieTexture movieToPlay = diskMovieDir.movie;

//Hook the movie texture to the current renderer
MeshRenderer ren = container.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
ren.material.mainTexture = movieToPlay ;    

movieToPlay.play();
}
```

Now you can call it by starting coroutine.

```
StartCoroutine(loadAndPlay());
```

I did not compile this so there might be a compile error but you can easily fix it if there is one. This should also work without problems if it compiles. Note that the url must start with **file:///**. If that didnt work, try **file://**

Comment: works great, im glad i posted i don't think i would have ever figured out that solution. Could this work with a live video stream as well

Comment: Not sure about video streaming. I heard from some one that it works with .ogg  extension only. So, maybe convert the video file to ogg  and that might work. I am assuming that you are using Unity instead of pro, so the solution to your problem is to learn C++, then write a plugin that decodes a video into frames. Send those frames(Video) over network. You need to learn about C++ Network Sockets(TCP/UDP). You can also do this with C# but you need the Unity Pro version to use C# Socket such as TCPListener. You dont need a pro for your own C++ plugin.

Comment: No, MovieTexture is not supported on Android/iOS